# ORM for JSON Parsing in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, orm

Can anyone tell me how should i do JSON Parsing using ORM method? is there any third party library available for this?
Or any web link if you guys know.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution for using the ORM method on iOS would be the SalesForce Mobile SDK.

> The Salesforce Mobile SDK for iOS and Android has implemented an ORM layer called SmartStore abstraction to SQLite, which uses FMDB on iOS and SQLCipher on Android ([modelVoice - Storing Data Offline](http://www.modelmetrics.com/tomgersic/storing-data-offline-with-salesforce-mobile-sdk-smartstore/)).

That's the only way I've heard how to do it, and I've searched pretty extensively.

You can download the SalesForce SDK [here](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Mobile_SDK).